# how to normalize right skewed data

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, data-mining, logistic-regression

[image: This is the unaltered histogram]I am trying to make a logistic regression model and am encountering a problem with one of the columns - Coapplicanticome. Basically when i view the data as a histogram the tail skews right, when i apply log, sqrt, exponent, boxcox, reciprocal transformations i end up with a bi-modal result where there is a straight line coming up from the 0 column or what ever constant i added to it to run ie  Coapplicanticome +1 and a normal looking curve to the side how do i deal with these 0's to make a normal curve or is there a better transformation i can do? [image: This is the log histogram] [image: and this is the logs probplot]

I have tried:
log, sqrt, exponent, boxcox, reciprocal transformations but none work well for predicting the value when checked against a pyplot

```
sns.distplot(train['CoapplicantIncome'],kde=False,fit = norm,bins=30)
stats.probplot(train['CoapplicantIncome'], dist="norm", plot=pylab)
plt.show()
```

this gives a skewed right curve

```
train['CoapplicantIncome_log'] = np.log(train.CoapplicantIncome + 1)
sns.distplot(train['CoapplicantIncome_log'],kde=False,fit=norm,bins=30)
```

this gives me a straight line coming up from 1 and an almost bell shaped curve to the right

but the probplot i get is completely disjointed

```
stats.probplot(train['CoapplicantIncome_log'], dist="norm", plot=pylab)
plt.show()
```

and its the same story for sqrt, exponent, boxcox but the reciprocal transformations doesnt work due to infinite value even with a constant added to it

i want to make a normalized column to enter it into the logistics regression model

Comment: You really should add the histogram (also after log transform), as it's hard to imagine what you mean by a straight line coming up from a *column*...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse sorry I did not know I could add an image I just put them in now, I'd be grateful for any help you can give me with this

Comment: Well, it *does* look as if your data has around 50% of values that are *exactly* zero. These will not magically become Gaussian with any deterministic transformation - they will still be the exact same value unless you add some randomness (which is not a recommendation). I'd suggest to (a) understand why the data is as it is, and (b) to model it conditionally - either the value is 0, or it's coming from some transformed normal distribution etc.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thank you for the help i was just checking to see if there was something obvious I missed that would explain it and that someone else could see it. I am afraid that i dont understand by what you mean by "or it's coming from some transformed normal distribution etc." could you please elaborate.

Comment: Even the non-zero values clearly don't look normal distributed.